# How to solve auto sample data storing in data collection in mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb

After creating a data collection in a particular database some sample data collection is added automatically daily in that database. After deleting those sample data collection from the database then again create sample data collection automatically. How can i stop auto sample data collection creating?

Comment: I think you need to identify the source of those sample data first and see how to stop from the source.

Answer (score -1):

you can set up automatic removal of documents older than a specified number of seconds by using the expireAfterSeconds parameter. To change the expiration value or to turn it off, get help from the documentation.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-automatic-removal/

Comment: OP's document may not have a suitable timestamp field for setting up TTL index. Moreover, setting up TTL index may unconditionally remove documents, which may jot be intended.